# How do I get my CSS to display my HTML with the display grid function properly?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[About Me Webpage with menu.css stylesheet](https://thebig15.github.io/islt_4355/aboutme.html)

How do I get the body to conform to the grid function to result in this layout?

[image: What My Page Looks Like]

[image: What I Want It To Look Like]

Comment: What you have done with HTML and CSS ? can you add code here?

Comment: You need to show what all have u done. Also there are CSS grid generators online to help u with your layout

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Hey i would use bootstrap 5.1 for gridlayouts. Here is an example code for a gridlayout

Here is the website of bootstrap and how to use it : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/

```
<div class="container mx-auto height">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 mt-2">
            <div class="article card">
                <div class="card-body bg-light">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mt-2">
            <div class="article card">
                <div class="card-body bg-light">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container mx-auto height">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mt-2">
            <div class="article card">
                <div class="card-body bg-light">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 mt-2">
            <div class="article card">
                <div class="card-body bg-light">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container mx-auto height">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mt-2">
            <div class="article card">
                <div class="card-body bg-light">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mt-2">
            <div class="article card">
                <div class="card-body bg-light">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mt-2">
            <div class="article card">
                <div class="card-body bg-light">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```